# Count like values then put count in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through column A- "Domains", and get total pages per domain. For each row, if the domain is the same, count the total. Once you get to a new domain, put that final page count in the top right box of the domain in Column C.

[image]

I'm new to VBA- I'm trying something like this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Sub TestScript()

    iMaxRow = 11000
    Range("B1").Select
    pagesCounter = 0    'loop counter for each page in site
    countEntryCell = 1  'where you put the total # pages for that site

    For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow
        'loop through column B, while domain name is the same... count rows
        'then put final count in count column
        If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then
            pagesCounter = pagesCounter + 1
        Else
           'Copy pages count to column c within the box
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'select next row
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**

Try this one:

```
Sub TestScript()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

        For Each c In rng
            If c.Value <> c.Offset(-1).Value Then
                'c.offset(,2) gives you column C
                c.Offset(, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, c.Value)
                'aplly border
                With c.Offset(-1).Resize(, 3).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can add a border around the group of same domains?